# Is "either" being properly used in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence

I'm not a native English-speaker. For some reason, I'm not sure about the usage of **either** in the following sentence:

> And it's not that I’m against traveling or studying abroad. It's just
>   that I'm not against staying in a same place **either**.

Is it being used correctly?

Comment: "Staying in a same place" is ungrammatical here. It should probably be "...I'm not against staying where I am either". Then the sentence is fine and _either_ is used grammatically. I might say it this way: "And I'm not against traveling or studying abroad. Neither am I against staying where I am now."

Comment: I did think about editing to correct that. *Staying in the same place* would be ok.

Comment: @janoChen: Can you explain why you thought it might *not* be a valid usage?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I wasn't sure whether to use `either` or `neither`. But I think Bill cleared my doubts.

Comment: @janoChen: Ah, right. Presumably you thought that because *neither* would be correct if you didn't negate the second sentence. But you'd need to change the word order too - ***Neither** am I against staying in the same place*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. [ODO on either](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/either?q=either):

> *conjunction & adverb*
>   **2** [adverb, with negative] used to indicate a similarity or link with a statement just made:
>      *You don’t like him, do you? I don’t either
>
>      it won’t do any harm, but won’t really help either*
>      • for that matter; moreover:
>         *I was too tired to go. And I couldn’t have paid, either*

This is exactly how it's used in your quote, indicating a link to the previous sentence. Note that it does depend on using the negative ("I'm not against...")